# Heartbeat functionality from AppInsights does not appear in azure portal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get the heartbeat feature of AppInsights sdk to work but I'm having some trouble.

I have a simple app (just the default ASP.net core 2.2 project created by using dotnet new webapp) running on a k8 cluster inside Azure and is configured with the following settings:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions
                                = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
            // Disables adaptive sampling.
            aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;

            // Disables QuickPulse (Live Metrics stream).
            aiOptions.EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = false;
            aiOptions.InstrumentationKey = InstrumentationKey;
            aiOptions.EnableHeartbeat=true;
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

However, I can't see any properties in Application Insights related to the heartbeat functionality. I can see other stuff like the kubernetes pod name, etc.

Am I missing some configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heartbeat feature is enabled by default as of base SDK 2.5.0 and the ability to configure the Heartbeat was added in 2.3.0-beta1.

I would suggest you to modify your startup file like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc();

    ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOpts = 
      new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
    aiOpts.EnableHeartbeat = true; // false to disable
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOpts);
    ...
}
```

Also add `using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions;` in the top of your file.
Configure the Heartbeat feature in code by modifying the **`IHeartbeatPropertyManager`** directly. You can do this when you first obtain the property manager via the **`TelemetryModules.Instance`** singleton.

```
 foreach (var md in TelemetryModules.Instance.Modules)
  {
    if (md is IHeartbeatPropertyManager heartbeatPropertyMan)
    {
      heartbeatPropertyMan.HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);
      heartbeatPropertyMan.ExcludedHeartbeatProperties.Add("osType");
      ...
```

Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: Okay. How do I query the heartbeat logs via insights?

Answer (score 1):

To query heartbeat events you can use the following KQL query:

```
customMetrics
| where name == "HeartbeatState"
```